# Automatizar pruebas de QA Selenium + Python + ChromeWebdriver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Estoy automatizando algunos procesos de QA y tengo algunas dudas en el camino que no me permiten avanzar.

Tengo los siguientes problemas:

-Necesito que al abrir el Chromewebdriver, éste elija automáticamente la pestaña que quiero de las devtools, siendo **Elements, Console, Recorder, Sources, etc.**

Lo que he podido hacer hasta ahora es, cuando se ejecuta el navegador, que la DevTools esté abierta, pero en su pestaña principal, que sería **Elements**

-Extraer información de los valores de una extensión (¿Es esto posible?) La extensión aparece en el DevTools.

-Añadir una especie de alerta que no permita avanzar si no se hace clic.

-Hacer una captura de pantalla (Pude hacerlo, pero sólo aparece la página web, y necesitaría que apareciera además de la web, la DevTools).

Comment: Probablemente te interese leer [la documentación](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/bidirectional/chrome_devtools/). La alerta se puede hacer, queda en ti programarla. En cuanto a la captura creo que no hay nada que puedas hacer.

Comment: Hola, gracias por el comentario Mateo, lei la documentacion anteriormente y pude crear una alerta, pero esta NO frenaba el proceso, eso seria lo ideal, que frene el proceso y solo permita seguir si se le da "el ok".

La alerta solo aparecia y desaparecia al instante

Comment: ¿Quieres una alerta en el propio navegador? Cuando automatizas el navegador es mejor que solo sea controlado por código y no interactúes manualmente. Sugiero que si estás en una aplicación de terminal, mandes un mensaje y que tengas que presionar enter para continuar o algo así. Lo importante es que ocupes el navegador solo para la automatización.

Comment: Si seria lo ideal, la idea es por ejemplo:

Quiero apretar el boton INGRESAR , pero antes de que se reprodusca la accion, salga una alerta que diga "SEGURO DESEA APRETAR ESTE BOTON?" o algo por el estilo.

Gracias

Comment: Qué tal un [`MessageBox`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/177312/13419694) (para Windows)? O quizá tkinter, que es una librería para hacer ventanas con python multiplataforma.